# Connection string not working in C# windows application

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

For some reasons, I am unable to establish a data connection using my connection string. I was doing with the below code

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cmd.Connection = connectionString;

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = " dbo.SelectAll";

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@tradeDate","201401");

param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.DbType = DbType.String;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

But for some reasons when I am initializing the connection property to my command using `cmd.Connection = connectioString`, is is throwing an exception as follows

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: Yeah, watch your types.  [Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx) expects a SqlConnection object, not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing the connection string needed to connect to the database and the actual SqlConnection.

try this (for your specific code):

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

According to MSDN here is a proper example:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString, string connectionString)
 {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Link to original article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I think you need just

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

You are try to do set your [`SqlCommand.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property with your connection string. But this property is for specify your `SqlConnection` object, not your connection string.

From documentation;

> Gets or sets the **SqlConnection** used by this instance of the
>   SqlCommand.

And since there is no implicit conversation from SqlConnection to string, that's why you get compile time error.

As a side note, use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
   cmd.Connection = con;
   ...
   ...
}
```

or you can use [`SqlConnection.CreateCommand()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create your `SqlCommand` associated your `SqlConnection` inside your *using statement* like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, great minds think alike, 4 second difference in almost the exact same response.